# Disabling nextcord button

Tags: button, discord, nextcord

**As title says, I'm trying to find a way how to disable the button for the person, who already interacted with it.**

Like when it reaches 5 interactions, it turns green. I had checked the GitHub official Nextcord repository and found the `counter.py` file, which includes the changing button color after the number of interactions. But I still need to find a way how to disable it for user who already interacted. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] so we can better understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the disabled property to True and edit the message with the new view.

If using the decorator in a View class it would look like this

```py
button.disabled = True
await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
```

Comment: Using your code above, disables the button for only one person or for everyone?

Comment: For everyone, the button is part of the message.

Comment: But I need a method to disable for person who interacted with it

Comment: Not possible unless you DM them the button or make it ephemeral so only they see it.
You can display a different message based on who clicked it, but the state of the button is part of the button itself, it can't be different to some people.